# Can't use both mouse and keyboard at the same time

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, xorg, mouse

When I use the keyboard, my mouse stopped. This is terrible when I playing a game.
But I can temporarily make them work together: while pressing `shift`, they can work together.
How to fix it?

I'm using GNOME or awesomewm, and my Linux is ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04, and this error are both on GNOMe and LXDE

Comment: Are you using the trackpad or an external mouse?

Comment: I am using the trackpad.
Both trackpad and kekboard are internal.

Answer (score 3):

With Gnome Tweaks... This can easily be fixed! :D

In gnome tweaks click the "Keyboard and Mouse" tab and uncheck the slider called "Disable while typing" in the Touchpad section

Your trackpad being disabled while typing is how the trackpad works by default :D

Comment: Are there any way to slove this problem in LXDE?(GNOME is laggy on my machine so i am using LXDE now.)

Comment: I never used LXDE in my life so I am afraid I cant help you here

However, I will be searching the internet for an article that can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379851) I found with the same question:
their method doesn't require you to install Gnome Tweaks:

Run the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

Comment: Good find - I use LXDE and I have this setting too. In future please do include information from links here on the site in case external links get moved or changed.

Comment: I switched to awesomewm now. can I use this method?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 23.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found this answer at Unix & Linux that uses `xinput` to solve this problem: [Mouse and keyboard don't work when used at the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385785/322816)

> The problem I was having involved the *Disable While Typing Enabled*
> feature of my trackpad. These are the steps I used to solve it.
>
> 1. Make sure `xinput` is installed.
> 2. Type `xinput` to find the name of the trackpad device. Mine was `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad`.
> 3. Run `xinput --list-props "DEVICE"` to list the properties of the device.
> 4. Go through the list until you find something like `Disable While Typing`.
> 5. Use `xinput --set-prop "DEVICE" ID_OF_PROPERTY 0`. For me, this was `xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" 294 0`